# Why does this equation work for finding n equidistant points around a circle?

Tags: java, math, geometry

For a problem, we have to graph n equidistant points around a circle. I didn't know how to do that, so I searched it up and found a solution, but I don't know why it works. Here is the equations I used for each point.

```java
StdDraw.point(Math.cos((i * 2 * Math.PI) / n) + 1, Math.sin((i * 2 * Math.PI) / n) + 1);
```

This was put in a for loop, so "i" is what number point it is and "n" is the number of points that need to be graphed. I added 1 at the end to translate it to fit inside the canvas.

Does anyone know why it works?

Comment: By math. Search for sine/cosine definition on a unit circle.

Comment: Look at the section called "Trigonometric functions on the unit circle" at the [Wiki Page for a Unit Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).  There is a beautiful animated GIF there showing the angle in radians corresponding to the point on the circle via Sin() and Cos().  The `i` and `n` are used to get a percentage of 2*PI, which is then passed to Sin() and Cos().

Comment: you can think of it as the root of equation `z^n = 1` where z is a complex number. See 
http://mathonline.wikidot.com/nth-roots-of-complex-numbers

Comment: Draw a sketch, and stare at it.

Answer (score 1):

Sine and Cosine output curves model all of the points along the circumference of a circle and they do this by being fed all of the possible angles that exist within a circle i.e 2*pi if you use radians. Now, if you feed 2*pi*(i/n) to sine and cosine that is giving each respective function n angles between 0 and 2*pi, and the output each spits out is then equidistant because you fed in equidistant angles, so you will receive equidistant points that fall at the ends of those angles that you fed in.

Look at a gif of sine and cosine around a circle, then a graph of sine and cosine and more will make sense.